# Problems with Z step

Tags: z-axis, extrusion

Recently I bought a Prusa i3 pro W (from Geeetech) and I've been struggling with something that is ruining all my printings. I attach a photo with what was supposed to be little "boxes":

[image: Controller display]

As you can see the Z distance is doing weird things, I think may can be fixed through this configurations, as it seems the Z axis is moving too much:

[image]

On the other hand, the form the printer is doing the skirt is also bothering me, I've tried a lot of configurations and I think it's a problem of over extrusion, but I'm a newbie and I don't really know what more could I do...

[image: Close up of failed print]

I'll really thank you for every answer because I've been a lot of days with this and I begin to feel really disappointed with all.. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! ^^' It's everything really desesperating.. Haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. as per base of the pink printout it looks like the bed is far below the nozzle (level the bed)
2. to check the Z steps/mm setting, the best way will be to home it, then from menu move Z by 50mm and check with a ruler or meter traveled distance.
3. then using a formula (requestedMove/measuredMove) * currentSteps set new value in to Z steps/mm setting. After that repeat the exercise until you will get no difference.

Comment: It's solved while I'm reading this but that was exactly the solution so thank you!
I've seen that some printers have this config and working well but in my case, I had to put it to 400 to gettings working properly.

Comment: @Juli15 you are very welcome! Happy printing